# Is there any way for waiting an element while other test steps are running with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

How can I check for 30 seconds, if the element showed up or not?

I would like to skip other steps while looking for a specific element and I want to click if the element shows up.

Sometimes the element will pop up after 2 seconds or 10 seconds (e.g. another page has opened) and I don't want to wait for finding the element.

I've tried the following, but if the element does not show up, the test will fail:

```java
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
MyLocator.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //turn default
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just read about Explicit Wait.

The Explicit Wait in Selenium is used to tell the Web Driver to wait for certain conditions (Expected Conditions) or maximum time exceeded before throwing “ElementNotVisibleException” exception.

For example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Scenario1Test.driver, 30); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator);
element.click()
```